# how to create a continuous variable?

Tags: r

I have a continuous dataset that looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame(age = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7))
```

1 is 13 y/o, 2 is 14 y/o, 3 is 15 y/o, 4 is 16 y/o, 5 is 17 y/o, 6 is 18 y/o, 7 is 19 y/o.

How can I replace `c(1:7)` to `c(13:19)` so that I can find the mean and SD of age in this dataset.

Comment: df$age <- df$age + 12

Answer (score 0):

It is easier as `R` indexing starts from 1 and this is in sequence

```
df$age <- (13:19)[df$age]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
df$age <- c(13:19)
```

then the mean and standard deviation are:

```
mean(df$age)
sd(df$age)
```